# Signing different types of messages with the same asymmetric key

Tags: public-key, signature, hmac, hkdf

I want to be able to sign different types of messages with the same asymmetric key. (For completeness, I am using Ed25519 for my signatures).

#### Why do I want to do this?

The same key is used to sign different types of messages. If I didn't use some method to differentiate between message types, an attacker might be able to ask me to sign one message of one type, and then use it as a message of another type.

#### Example crude solution

For a quick prototype, I used the following crude method.

To sign a message of type 1:

$\operatorname{Sign}[\text{key}](\text{"type1" }||\text{ message}_1)$

To sign a message of type 2:

$\operatorname{Sign}[\text{key}](\text{"type2" }||\text{ message}_2)$

I have a feeling that this is not the best way to get good separation between message types. This is especially true if one type string is a substring of another type string. I remember for example, that HMAC and hkdf use a more sophisticated mechanism (They don't just concatenate).

I don't want to reinvent the wheel here. Is there a common practice to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the prefixes `type1` `type2` etc.. are distinct, of equal size, and consistently inserted before everything signed, what's proposed is perfectly fine, and common practice.

---

That prefixes are distinct and of equal size is a simple and foolproof (thus good) way to implement the necessary and sufficient requirement: *no prefix shall be the start of another prefix*.

If for some reason prefixes must be of different size, possible conventions insuring that this requirement is met include:

- The size in byte of the prefix is before the prefix, on 1 byte (Pascal string convention).
- A special terminating byte is at the end of all prefixes, and not used elsewhere in a prefix. Common choices include the byte 0x00 (C string convention) or a separator like `:`
- Using the hash (SHA-512/256) of distinct string prefixes, as proposed in [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/59690/555#comment131234_59693). Since that's constant-size, the requirement boils down to using string prefixes that do not collide, and we do not even know how to make otherwise.

At the upper end of the complexity spectrum: everything signed could be per an appropriate [ASN.1 grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One). Watch out for the complexity degenerating into interoperability issues, or even exploitable flaws.

Comment: If your prefixes do not satisfy these conditions, you can prepend the length of the type you prepend. If you can deviate a tiny bit from Ed25519, you could use something like Keccak's TupleHash to solve it too.

Comment: @fgrieu: What if I prepend sha512/256("typestring") in the beginning as a solution for the variable size? Can this be a reasonable solution?

Comment: @real You could do that, and if anyone broke it then they would almost certainly have a way to find SHA-2 collisions, but surely length("typestring") is easier to compute than sha512/256("typestring")?